# html <br> tags are appearing in paragraph while using n2blr

Tags: php, html

I had used this below href code for fetching the data from database & sharing it on whatsapp.

```
 <a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo nl2br($row['invite']); ?> -:Flash-Downloads.in:-">Share</a>
```

the output i want is like this

```
Mark Robinson
USA
555454545
```

while i m getting this output

```
Mark Robinson<br>
USA<br>
555454545<br>
```

Any Solution to remove `<br>` tags and for printing the data same as it was inserted in Database(in paragraph)?

Comment: <a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo nl2br($row['invite']); ?> -:Flash-Downloads.in:-">Share</a>

Comment: <a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo nl2br($row['invite']); ?> -:Flash-Downloads.in:-">Share</a>

Comment: this is the code i had used...!!

<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo nl2br($row['invite']); ?> -:Flash-Downloads.in:-">Share</a>

Comment: Just edit your question, do not paste in comments. Read this before asking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using nl2br if you dont want to get `<br>`

nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

Description

```
string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )
```

Returns string with `'<br />'` or `'<br>'` inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

**EDIT**

you can encode URL to pass new line as

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo urlencode($row['invite']); ?> -:Flash-Downloads.in:-">Share</a>
```

**EDIT**

use rawurlencode() to encode whitespace to %20 instead of +

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo rawurlencode($row['invite']); ?> -:Flash-Downloads.in:-">Share</a>
```